# R: smoothing binned data in barplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, smoothing, density-plot

The data describe the distribution of commodities (apples and bananas) on the trees along the road between two villages, Villariba and Villabajo, which is 4000+ m long. The data are either already binned (i.e. are given summarized over every 500 m), or are supplied with big errors of locations, so binning by 500 m is natural. We want to process and plot them as a smoothed *post factum* distributions via kernel smoothing. There are two obvious ways to do this in `ggplot2` package. First read data (long format).

```
library(ggplot2)
databas<-read.csv(text="dist,stuff,val
500,apples,10
1250,apples,25
1750,apples,55
2250,apples,45
2750,apples,25
3250,apples,10
3750,apples,5
500,bananas,7
1250,bananas,14
1750,bananas,20
2250,bananas,17
2750,bananas,10
3250,bananas,30
3750,bananas,20")
```

The first try is a boring barplot with `geom_col()`. Next, we can use two ggplot2 facilities contained in density plots (`geom_density()`) and in smoothing curves (`stat_smooth()` or equivalently `geom_smooth()`) respectively. The three ways are realized as follows:

```
    p1<-ggplot(databas,aes(dist,val,fill=stuff,alpha=0.5))+geom_col(alpha=0.5,position="dodge")
    p2<-ggplot(databas,aes(dist,val,fill=stuff))+stat_smooth(aes(y=val,x=dist),method="gam",se=FALSE,formula=y~s(x,k=7))
    p3<-ggplot(databas,aes(dist,val,fill=stuff,alpha=0.5))+geom_density(stat="identity")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,nrow=3)
```

[image: three plots with density smoothing in ggplot2]

There are shortcomings of every method. The superimposed density plot (bottom graph) is the most desired design, but the option `stat="identity"` (since data are binned) prevents from creating fine-looking smooth distribution, like it were normally. The `stat_smooth()` option gives almost excellent curves, but these are just curves. So: how to combine the coloring from density plot and the smoothing from smoothing function? That is either to smoothen data in geom_density(), or to fill the space with semi-transparent colors under `stat_smooth()` curves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like your `gam` fits, you can use `stat = "smooth"` within `geom_ribbon` to draw the curves.  The trick is to set `ymin` to 0 and `ymax` to `..y..`, which is the special variable created by `stat_smooth` that is the predicted line.

```
ggplot(databas, aes(x = dist, y = val, fill = stuff)) +
    geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ..y..), alpha = .5,
                method = "gam", se=FALSE, formula = y ~ s(x, k = 7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
library(ggplot2)
p2 <-  ggplot(databas, aes(dist ,val ,fill = stuff)) + stat_smooth(aes(y = val,x = dist), method = "gam",se = FALSE,formula = y ~ s(x, k = 7))
```

Extract curves with `ggplot_build`

```
p2_build = ggplot_build(p2)
p2_fill <- data_frame(
  x = p2_build$data[[1]]$x,
  y = p2_build$data[[1]]$y,
  group = factor(p2_build$data[[1]]$group, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("apples","bananas")))
```

add color with `geom_area`

```
p2 + geom_area(data = p2_fill[p2_fill$group == "apples", ], 
                   aes(x=x, y=y), fill = "red", alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_area(data = p2_fill[p2_fill$group == "bananas", ], 
            aes(x=x, y=y), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

complete answer:

```
ggplot(databas, aes(dist, val, color = stuff))+
  stat_smooth(aes(y = val,x = dist), method = "gam",se = FALSE, formula = y ~ s(x, k = 7))+
  geom_area(data = p2_fill[p2_fill$group == "apples", ], 
            aes(x=x, y=y), fill =  "#F8766D", alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = F)+
  geom_area(data = p2_fill[p2_fill$group == "bananas", ], 
            aes(x=x, y=y), fill = "#00BFC4", alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = F)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]